# Trying to create a list dotted list in lwc component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, slds, slds-grid

LWC component-

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <p class="slds-text-heading_label slds-m-bottom_small">
            Sample
        </p>
        <div class="myapp">
            <ul class="slds-list_dotted slds-m-top_large">
                <li>Account 1</li>
                <li>Account 2</li>
                <li>Account 3</li>
                <li>Account 4</li>
                <li>Account 5</li>
                <li>Account 6</li>
                <li>Account 7</li>
                <li>Account 8</li>
                <li>Account 9</li>
                <li>Account X</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>
```

Output:

[image]

I wish to use `slds-list_dotted` to get a dotted list( expected list below ). I tried the same in LWC playground and I am able to see it correctly however doesn't work in the above component. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Where you have put this component? Maybe some CSS is getting overridden. Try to view this component in the Aura app with SLDS.

Comment: Added it to an app page. This is the only component there. I don't have any css.

Comment: Part of - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_design_system/lightning-design-system3

Comment: I tried this in my org, and it is working fine. maybe some other component is using css from static resource, or the theme is overriding the css.Inspecting can help

Comment: worked fine for me too  try redeploying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fun. When I tried this in the app builder it just worked fine. But when I saw it actually on the Page. It was not there.

When I inspected found that some `injected stylesheet` is this. Which looked like this.

```
ul:not(.browser-default) {
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

So when I searched this found this [link](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2786) and the solution in there worked like a charm. I just had to convert the provided SCSS to CSS.

**Here is the solution, just add below CSS in your component's .css file.**

```
ul:not(.browser-default) li {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Comment: interesting. Can't understand why would there be a style sheet injected here. What use of slds-list_dotted if we can't use it directly here

Comment: not sure, but there is some issue related css in general and not specific for salesforce

Comment: What do you mean by - "app builder it just worked fine". Did you add the component to an app page/record page?

Comment: @sfdcbat  Yes, in the app builder preview it was showing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have used slds class in my code and it is working.

```
<ol class="slds-list_ordered">
            <template for:each={morningBreakFast} for:item="item">
                <li key={item}> {item}</li>
            </template>
</ol>
```

for more information please refer below vertical list article from slds,
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/name-value-list/#site-main-content

Answer (score 0):

Try using slds-text-longform.
Example:
`<div class="slds-text-longform slds-align_absolute-center"> <ul class="slds-list_dotted"> <li>abc</li> <li>abc</li> </ul> </div>`